# How to hide loading indicator in ag grid server side row model?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using an ag-grid server-side data source and I used ten stack query to cache the data if so I want to hide the loader when data comes from the cache.

```
 const onGridReady = useCallback(
    (onGridReadyParams: GridReadyEvent) => {
      console.log("Grid is ready!");
      const dataSource: IServerSideDatasource = { getRows };
      onGridReadyParams.api.setServerSideDatasource(dataSource);
      gridApiRef.current = onGridReadyParams.api;
      setColumnApi(onGridReadyParams.columnApi);
    },
    [currentView]
  );
```

[![loading indicator][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvzAj.png